# Feedparser newbie questions

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

After a break from Python(and I knew very little then!) I'm coming back to it for a project(hopefully!).  I want to do some parsing using Feedparser & need a few hints to start.  Before anyone shouts, I have searched Google and read the docs, but I'm a bit too rusty unfortunately!(So please don't lmgtfy me!)

If I have a rss feed, then how would I parse it in order that I get each of the item titles seperately which can then be inserted into a web page?

Hope that makes sense.  Many thanks for any responses.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I mean so I can label each title seperately and use each one where I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import feedparser
url = "http://..."
feed = feedparser.parse(url)
for post in feed.entries:
    title = post.title
    print(title)
```

If you'd like to extract just the third post, then you could use

```
post=feed.entries[2]
```

(since python uses 0-based indexing). Printing `post` might be helpful; it'll show you what information is available:

```
print post
```

And finally, to grab just the title of the third post:

```
print post['title']
```

or

```
print post.title
```

Comment: Have clarified above.  Thanks though!

Comment: @James: I'm sorry -- I don't understand what you mean by "label each title separately". Can you give an example? Maybe an rss feed so we can speak concretely?

Comment: Each rss feed has a certain number of items, each of which are stories.  Each of these items has a different title.  So, if I parsed that using Feedparser, how would I use just the title of the third item?  Hope that makes more sense!